# How to pass lighthouse location : cronexpression + AWS + Python + lighthouse

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, cron, lighthouse

I have created AWS ec2 instance and a python script to automate lighthouse reports

I have successfully ran the lighthouse python code in AWS server manually by running below lines
ubuntu@ip:~/Python_lighthouse$ python3 SEO_PYTHON_LIGHTHOUSE_lighthouse.py

However, I am struggling to run the same code via cronjob.

*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Python_lighthouse/SEO_PYTHON_LIGHTHOUSE_lighthouse.py /home/ubuntu/Python_lighthouse/lighthouse.log 2>&1

(above cronjob working fine but getting error: /bin/sh/: lighthouse not found)

Following version and locations:
which npm
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.5.0/bin/npm
which node
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.5.0/bin/node
which lighthouse
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.5.0/bin/lighthouse

I have tried passing lighthouse to my cronjob like this but didn't work for me
*/10 * * * * /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v17.5.0/bin/lighthouse && /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/Python_lighthouse/SEO_PYTHON_LIGHTHOUSE_lighthouse.py /home/ubuntu/Python_lighthouse/lighthouse.log 2>&1

please correct me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Where do you see the error "/bin/sh/: lighthouse not found"? What is producing that error?

Comment: in log file generated from my cron expression